# why google map is not pointing to my current location in ionic cordova

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, ionic3

Why i'm unable to point `marker` on my `current` `location`.  the `marker` is pointing to somewhere else.

**here is a screenshot:**

[image]

**below is my complete code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';


import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 LatLng,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';        

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-google-map-test',
  templateUrl: 'google-map-test.html',
})

export class GoogleMapTestPage {


  constructor(...,public googleMaps: GoogleMaps,private geolocation : Geolocation) {
  }

 ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.mapHandler2();       
  }

  mapHandler2(){


              // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
     let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

     let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

     let LatLang: LatLng = new LatLng(43.0741904,-89.3809802); 


          // create CameraPosition 
       let position: any = {
          target: LatLang,    
          zoom: 18,
          tilt: 30
       };     


        map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
         console.log('Map is ready!');
         // Now you can add elements to the map like the marker
        //   map.moveCamera(position);

         // create new marker
        let markerOptions:any = {
            position: LatLang,
            title: 'Ionic'
        };

        const marker:any = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
            .then((marker: Marker) => {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            });


         this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

             let LatLang: LatLng = new LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);


               map.setCameraTarget(LatLang);
               map.setCameraZoom(18);

                let defPosition: any = {
                    target: LatLang,    
                    zoom: 18,
                    tilt: 30
                 };


                map.moveCamera(defPosition);


                let markerOptions:any = {
                    position: LatLang,
                    title: 'Your Current Location'
                };

                const marker:any = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    .then((marker: Marker) => {
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                  });     


          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err); 
            alert('location error');            
          });

        });

  }

}
```

> **Thinking that i'm not getting co-ordinates i changed my code like below code, which is not showing even google map**

**below is code:(Not Showing Anything)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';


import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 LatLng,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';      


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-google-map-test',
  templateUrl: 'google-map-test.html',
})

export class GoogleMapTestPage {


  constructor(...,public googleMaps: GoogleMaps,private geolocation : Geolocation) {
  }

 ionViewDidLoad() {

     this.getCurrentLocation();           
  }

  getCurrentLocation(){

             this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

             let LatLang: LatLng = new LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

             this.mapHandler2(LatLang);

          }, (err) => {
            console.log(err); 
            alert('location error');            
          });
  }


  mapHandler2(LatLang){          


              // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
     let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

     let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);


        map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
         console.log('Map is ready!');

               let defPosition: any = {
                    target: LatLang,    
                    zoom: 18,
                    tilt: 30
                 };


                map.moveCamera(defPosition);


                let markerOptions:any = {
                    position: LatLang,
                    title: 'Your Current Location'
                };

                const marker:any = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    .then((marker: Marker) => {
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                  }); 




        });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a bug of Google Maps native API(I guess you use Android).
Adding a marker after camera moving should be fine.

Try like this (with `@ionic-native/core@4.4.2` and `@ionic-native/google-maps@4.4.2`):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';


import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMap,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 ILatLng,
 CameraPosition,
 MarkerOptions,
 Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';      


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-google-map-test',
  templateUrl: 'google-map-test.html',
})

export class GoogleMapTestPage {


  constructor(...,private geolocation : Geolocation) {
  }

 ionViewDidLoad() {
     this.getCurrentLocation();
  }

  getCurrentLocation(){

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let yourPosition: ILatLng = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      this.mapHandler2(yourPosition);

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err); 
      alert('location error');
    });
  }


  mapHandler2(yourPosition){

    let map: GoogleMap = GoogleMaps.create('map');


    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
      console.log('Map is ready!');

      let defPosition: any = {
        target: yourPosition,    
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      };

      map.moveCamera(defPosition).then(() => {
        let markerOptions:any = {
            position: yourPosition,
            title: 'Your Current Location'
        };
        return map.addMarker(markerOptions);
      })
      .then((marker: Marker) => {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
      });

  }

}
```

Comment: i have  tried your code on android but it showing blank, can you please check it. on your android. please

Comment: Did you add div container having id as map in your html file?? and set height of the div container?

Answer (score 0):

To go along with wf9a5m75's answer this is the HTML and SCSS I had. As said in the comments having the div id as map is pivotal to the GoogleMap displaying (see first line of code in the function mapHandler2). Hopefully it helps.
HTML:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Location</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Ionic GoogleMaps Demo</h3>
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```
page-location {
  #map{
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

My Ionic page is named Location so the you will probably need to change the first line of your scss file to properly reflect the your project.